# Jmeter stop test when time reaches threshold

Tags: jmeter

We're running a test case for load testing, over different servers. What we want to do is, given that test case, stop if we can see a performance decrease, based on a response time threshold.

What we have now is `threadgroup` defined, and inside it, an HTTP request defined plus a view table for output. What should I do to put this control in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add [Duration Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion) and specify threshold there
2. In your [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) set "Action to be taken after a Sampler error" to `Stop Test`.

Above steps will stop your test after first occurrence of response time exceeding the threshold.

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article for more information on how to conditionally set pass/fail criteria in your JMeter test.

P.S.

- Remove View Results Table listener (or disable it) during load test execution as it consumes a lot of resources.
- Run your load test [in non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) as JMeter GUI is not designed for running the actual load test and may be a bottleneck in case of more or less severe load.